# Wordpress login locks up my cPanel/WHM vps

Tags: wordpress

I've recently been hacked on my VPS, and have since then installed some extra security plugins in WHM. Well I'm not exactly sure, but sometime after that happened, each time I tried to login to any wordpress installation on my VPS, it just hangs until it times out. During this time my VPS is totally inaccessible, as well as the sites hosted on it. Then approx 15 minutes later, the VPS is back p again.

Does anyone have any ideas or tips for me to rectify this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take a WAG without being able to see your config and source, I would say you still have a problem in your code.  I.e. Some source code is messed up.  Maybe from the hack?

I would do a full reinstall of Wordpress (the latest version).

Once your server was exploited, who knows what code got changed.

Some examples of what could be happening...
PHP goes into some crazy loop utilizing and blocking all resources (wouldn't be unheard of).

So, I'd do a fresh reinstall of Wordpress.

Honestly though, your whole VPS could be compromised.  I'd get a new one and start rebuilding your server on that.  Yes, it'll take a lot of time, but it's the most guaranteed way to make sure your server is clean and free of additional security issues.

Comment: Thanks. I'm busy doing a full reinstall of my server environment, and copying the sites across 1 by 1 to make sure it's ok. I've also tightened security on the new server etc. etc. But yes, you're right, it looks like my wordpress installations have been copromised.